# Problemas con Jaxb2Marshaller al crear clases Java

Tags: java, wsdl, xsd

Tengo un proyecto java que lee archivos XSD y WSDL para crear clases Java con el siguiente código:

```
    @Bean("BookingMarshaller")
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
      Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
      marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.project.booking","com.project.ticketdocument");
      return marshaller;
    }
```

A la hora de crear las clases me las está creando con javax, sin embargo necesito que se creen con jakarta.

He incluido las librerías correspondientes a jakarta y tengo el siguiente plugin en el pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

¿Qué más me faltaría para que usara jakarta en las clases generadas? Es la primera vez que toco esto y, aún con la documentación, no me aclaro mucho.

Gracias